# recompile of apk file does not work any longer

Tags: android, apk, recompile

since I upgraded my Android Studio I have a little problem.
I could decompile/recompile/sign and zip the Release 1 without problems. The file size of the original compiled version is quite similar than the recompiled version.

```
rel.    source      recompiled
1   38 MB       39 MB   ok
2   53 MB       43 MB   nok
3   54 MB       43 MB   nok
4   54 MB       43 MB   nok
```

When I try the same procedure for release 2, 3 or 4 (with were compiled with newer Android Studio), I am not able to install a decompiled apk file. Moreover, I noticed that the filesize of the recompiled apk files is ~10 MB smaller than the original compiled file made with Android Studio.

Decompiling:

```
apktool d -r Android_Sutio.apk
```

Recompiling:

```
apktool b -o recompiled.apk ./decompiled/
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ../my.keystore ./recompiled.apk alias_name
zipalign -p -f 4 recompiled.apk recompiled_signed_zip.apk
```

I can install all the recompiled apf files, but release 2, 3 and 4 are ot startable.

Why is this not working any longer?

Thanks.